# How to get the content height of a UIWebView in iPhone sdk, objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the content size of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

Hai Guys,

I got a problem while lodaing the htmlString into UIWebView, I have set the frame height of a webview in iphone is 265 always.

```
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 41, 320, 265)];
```

Is there any property to get content height of a UIWebView.

If I got the content only one or two lines then it is looking odd below the two lines. How can I make it dynamic. Please suggest any solution.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: You might wanna check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview/3937599#3937599) on a similar question that doesn't need any JavaScript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"]
```

in your `webViewDidFinishLoad` method.

Comment: I want to set the webView frame height if we know the height before loading. The string which is returning from given method is in piexls or what.

Comment: Sorry not to mention it. It's the height of the content in pixels. When you have that value you can set your webview frame height. I think there's no way to know the height before loading the page.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for your response, But problem not solved.

Comment: The pixels I am getting is to large like 517, 233, if the content is only one line code

Comment: Does your problem is that you don't want to display the webview before knowing the exact size?

Comment: Even after loading i want to change the webview frame height, How can I

Comment: If you are loading page from a string you have to be sure it is a correct HTML document. This works:
NSString * html = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"it\" dir=\"ltr\"><html><head><title>aaaa</title></head><body>Test!</body></html>";

Comment: if the content height is less than webview frame height then this method always return the webview frame height :( so sad :(